# Is it possible to filter a table reference in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the following table in Excel:

[image]

Is there a way to reference a row by some filter criteria? For example, something like:

`=MyTable[@Age=2]` to get the row with that value? For the answer I would like to get the following (the row itself, with or without the headers):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Filter or Match Data in an Excel Table

**`FILTER`**

With Headers

```
=LET(h,MyTable[#Headers],d,MyTable,c,MyTable[Age],cVal,2,
    f,FILTER(d,c=cVal,""),
IF(f="",h,VSTACK(h,f)))
```

Without Headers

```
=LET(d,MyTable,c,MyTable[Age],cVal,2,
FILTER(d,c=cVal,""))
```

[image]

**`INDEX/XMATCH`**

With Headers

```
=LET(h,MyTable[#Headers],d,MyTable,c,MyTable[Age],cVal,2,
    sc,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d)),
    m,IFERROR(INDEX(d,TOCOL(XMATCH(c,cVal),3),sc),""),
IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN("",,m))=0,h,VSTACK(h,m)))
```

Without Headers

```
=LET(d,MyTable,c,MyTable[Age],cVal,2,
    sc,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d)),
IFERROR(INDEX(d,TOCOL(XMATCH(c,cVal),3),sc),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Excel, whether the so-called dynamic array functions are supported or not:

- [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)
- [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)
- VLOOKUP (“legacy”) with additional efforts as it returns only one column at the time; and other limitation such as the reference column has to be left to the returning column

Answer (score 0):

**You can use an ADO query**

This way is easy to set multiple criteria.
Call the sub tableRowsWhere with four arguments:

a) the listobject

b) a string whitch has the sql WHERE criteria without the "WHERE"

c) the destination cell to copy the result

d) an optional boolean indicator to copy or not the headers.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub tableRowsWhere(lo As ListObject, sqlCriteria As String, _
              dest As Range, Optional copyHeaders As Boolean = True)

   Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String, table As String
   
   table = " [" & lo.Range.Worksheet.Name & "$" & lo.Range.Address(0, 0) & "] "
   sql = "SELECT * FROM" & table & "WHERE " & sqlCriteria
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With connection
      .CursorLocation = 3
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
      .Open
      Set recSet = .Execute(sql)
   End With
   If copyHeaders = True Then
      With lo.HeaderRowRange
         Call .Copy(dest.Resize(.rows.CountLarge, .Columns.CountLarge))
      End With
      Set dest = dest.Cells(1).Offset(1, 0)
   End If
   Call dest.CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
   recSet.Close
   connection.Close
   Set recSet = Nothing
   Set connection = Nothing
End Sub


Sub tester()
   Dim r As Range, criteria As String
   Const QT = """"
   criteria = "([HEAD6] = 'YES')"
   Call tableRowsWhere(Me.ListObjects("TABLE6"), Replace(criteria, "'", QT), Me.Range("A32"))
End Sub
```

[image]